# New PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null even when connection is right

Tags: php, pdo

i have tried to research everywhere and i have no idea why i am getting this error.i am using PDO connection and am new to it.

working on a message poster project.

here is my code.

```
<?php

class StatusPoster{

    private $db=NULL;

    const DB_SERVER='localhost';
    const DB_USER='root';
    const DB_PASSWORD='';
    const DB_NAME='status_poster';


    public function _construct(){
           $dsn ='mysql:dbname='.self::DB_NAME.';host'.self::DB_SERVER;

                try{
            $this->db = new PDO($dsn, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);           

        }catch (PDOException $e) {            
            throw new Exception('connection failed : '.$e->getMessage());
        }
      return $this->db; 


    } 

    public function getStatusPosts(){
        $statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name,image,Status,timestamp FROM status ORDER BY timestamp DESC,id");
        $statement->execute();

        if($statement->rowCount()>0){
            return $statement->fetchAll();
        }
        return false;


    }  


}
 $status = new StatusPoster();
?>
```

here is code to display the information from the database.

```
<?php
                    if (is_array($result))
                    foreach($result as $row){
                        echo '
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">
                                     <img class="left" src="images/user/' .
                    $row['image'] . '" alt="picture">
                    </a>
                    <div class="content left">
                    <a href="#">' . $row['name'] . '</a>
                    <div class="status">' . $row['status'] . '</div>
                    <span class="localtime" data-timestamp="' .
                    $row['timestamp'] . '"></span>
                  </div>
                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    </li>
                    ';
                    }
                    ?>
```

I will be greatful if someone really points the problem to me.

Comment: Try to `var_dump($this->db);` to debug. The error message seems to indicate that it's not a proper instantiated PDO object.  Also your query is riddled with [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) which will cause further problems

Comment: i could not figure out what you meant. sorry! still having the same problem

Comment: i have tried var_dump(); but its not working also, it says NULL, Thank you for your good heart though it did not help

Comment: Where did you put the `var_dump($this->db)`?  Make sure it's right after this line in your `__construct` - `$this->db = new PDO($dsn, self::DB_USER, self::DB_PASSWORD);`

Comment: still finding the same error and it says the error is on line 38. in the getStatusPosts() function

 `$statement = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name,image,Status,timestamp FROM status ORDER BY timestamp DESC,id");`

will be happy really if oneday i ever find out the error. thanx @Aaron W.